# Can't save object in Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm having an issue when running a function in **Cloud Code**. It is supposed to check the existence of an object and, if it does exist, create a new user:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createUser", function(request, response) {

    // Query the existing company by id
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("Company"));
    query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.company.existing.id);
    query.find().then(function(result){

        var user = new Parse.User();

        user.set("username", request.params.username);
        user.set("password", request.params.username);
        user.set("email", request.params.email);
        user.set("permissions", ["User"]);

        var company = result[0];

        user.signUp(null, {
            success: function(user){
                // Asign company ACL for User write permission
                var cACL = company.getACL();
                cACL.setWriteAccess(user.id, true);
                company.setACL(cACL);
                // Save company
                company.save();
                console.log(company);

                // Establish user-company relationship
                var cRelation = user.relation("associated");
                cRelation.add(company);
                // Save user
                user.save();
                console.log(user);

                // Finish
                response.success(user);
            },
            error: function(user, error){
                response.error(JSON.stringify({code: -8000, message: "User creation failed"}));
            }
        });

    }, function(error){
        response.error(JSON.stringify({code: -8001, message: "Invalid company"}));
    });

});
```

I first query **Parse** for the existence of said object. If it does exist I create a new user with the parameters received. In the completion block of the user creation I assign the proper *ACLs* (to the *company* object) and later on save them. That's when I encounter the first issue: **the *ACLs* are not saved** (checked in the dashboard). I `console.log` the company for debugging purposes and it shows the *ACLs* are correctly set. So I assume it must be a **saving problem**.


**NOTE:** The user is created, but whatever I try to do later doesn't work.


Later on I add this object to a relationship previously defined in the dashboard, but I have the same problem with that: the relationship **does not come up in the dashboard**, even though when I `console.log` the object it shows that the relationship was properly set.


I'm lost here. I don't understand why this isn't working and I've read tons of online documentation and still can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after a day of work I finally found out my problem. I had *ACLs* set everywhere and I had no privilege for saving the objects I was trying to save. **So saving was indeed failing**.

I should note that if you are having the same problem I did, you can easily solve it using the **Master Key**. To do so, you need to call `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` before executing any requests that must be authenticated.

This only works in *Cloud Code*, and you should definitely know what you are doing when you use the *Master Key* because it basically gives read and write privileges **to anyone, everywhere, for everything**. So make sure your logic is flawless because you might get big security problems if it's not used wisely. As *Uncle Ben* said: *With great power comes great responsibility*.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: For anyone reading this in 2017, I'd like to mention that `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` is discontinued, and you should pass `{useMasterKey: true}` as an option to any function you wish to run elevated.